# SQL Server Agent Job is not invoking Powershell Script

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have Powershell Script that converts XLS files into CSV file(s). it is working fine if I run this script manually but it is not working with SQL Server Agent Job. SQL Server Agent job is not throwing any error but also script is not doing anything as it is not converting XLS file into CSV.

**Code of Powershell Script (Convert2CSV.ps1)**

```
$Dir="C:\Source\TEST\Deployment\ReportOutput"
$Files =Get-Childitem $Dir -filter "*.xls"
foreach ($file in $Files)
{
    $excelFile = "$Dir\"+$File

    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)

    foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets) 
    {
        $ws.SaveAs($excelFile.Replace(".xls","") + ".csv", 6)
    }
    $Excel.Quit()
}
```

**SQL Server Agent Job Step**
[image]

**Below is the Powershell ExecutionPolicy on the machine. Sql Server and Powershell Script is on the same machine**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no error handling in the PowerShell script so you will struggle to fully debug it anyway.

As it is failing from SQL Agent then I suspect it is down the the Service Account and permissions.

Comment: can you please share more details on Service Account and permissions. I mean, where and what should i change to make it working as expected?

Comment: I would suggest that you create a Proxy to handle this so that it can remain with lowest possible permissions.  Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I have tried with Proxy in sql Server Agent job but getting same problem

Comment: What steps did you follow with the Proxy? What credential did you use?  Have you tried adding some debug steps into the PowerShell to see if it reaches any of the specific commands?